# How to send some arguments along with CreateView and then access them in the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I was making a online store kind of website and am not able to make my add to cart option to work properly. I haven't yet linked the rest of the code to the button and am using an another link to operate it currently as you can see in the code.I want the form to submit the item name and brand automatically. Please suggest some way.

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/addtocart/$', views.ItemAdd.as_view(), name='addtocart'),
```

models.py

```
class Mycart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class ItemAdd(CreateView):
    model = Mycart
    fields = ['name', 'brand', 'quantity']
    template_name = 'products/add_to_cart.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

add_to_cart.html

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %} {% block body %}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ object.name }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="{{ object.brand }}">
  <br>
  <p>Enter Quantity</p>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" value="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What type of arguments do you want to send?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? Should the name and brand values be initialized without the user's input?

Comment: yes sir i want the form to send the name and brand value of the item the user has looked and has selected add cart without him typing it again.For now the addtocart is being accessed in a url without the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that, when user click on item (product), you want automatically add name and brand to form, so user only need to enter quantity and submit form? Maybe you can try like this:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        product_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_pk)
        context.update({
            'product': product
        })
        return context
```

Now you can access product in your template and get name and brand:

```
   {{ product.name }}
   {{ product.brand }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Formview. Then you will have:

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product')
```

forms.py

```
class AddCartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, product):
        instance = super(AddCartForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.product = product
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class AddCartView(FormView):
    form_class = AddCartForm
    success_url = '/'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_pk = kwargs.get('product_pk')
        self.product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_pk)
        return super(
            AddCartView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kw):
        context = super(AddCartView, self).get_context_data(**kw)
        context.update(product=self.product)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(product=self.product)
        return super(AddCartView, self).form_valid(form)
```

add_cart.html

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %} {% block body %}

<form action="{% url 'cart:add' product.pk %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```